# Return the working day number in each calendar month

Tags: sql, date, t-sql, sql-server-2008, calendar

I am trying to calculate the working day numbers in each calendar month. For example, in the month of November, there are 22 working days (1, 2, 3, ..., 22). Saturday and Sunday will be seen as the preceding Friday (e.g. November 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, ..., 22).

[image]

The logic I wrote below didn't work. Please can anyone solve this for me?

```sql
SELECT Date 
     , datepart(DW, DATE) AS DayName
     , DATENAME(DW, DATE) ax
     , datepart(DW, DATE)-1 AS DayName1
     , CASE WHEN datepart(DW,DATE)-1 IN (0,6) THEN 5 ELSE datepart(DW,DATE)-1 END bx
FROM [STAGING_4_6_DIM_CALENDAR_V2] 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: The case statement returns this output, which is not what I intend to achieve 1
2
3
4
5
5
5
1
2
3
4
5
5
5

Comment: You said `Saturday and Sunday will be seen as the preceding Friday` ... your current output looks correct to me.

Comment: Though the above is language specific. `WEEKDAY` returns different values depending on your `@@DATEFIRST` setting, which is linked to the language setting of your `LOGIN`. Personally, as you have a calendar table, I would be storing the weekday number in there.

Comment: The day number has to continue to number 22 for the month - November. But the query isn't doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use a running sum:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Date
         , CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date) IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS wd
    FROM t
)
SELECT Date, SUM(wd) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date) ORDER BY Date)
FROM cte
```

For November 2021 it will return:

```
1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,13,14,15,15,15,16,17,18,19,20,20,20,21,22
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT S.[DATE]
    ,X.WeekDayNumber
    ,DATENAME(dw, [DATE]) AS ax
    ,5 * X.WeekOfMonth +
        CASE
            WHEN X.WeekDayNumber > 5
            THEN 5
            ELSE X.WeekDayNumber
        END
        - X.FirstDayOfMonthOffset AS bx
FROM [STAGING_4_6_DIM_CALENDAR_V2] S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
        (
            -- iso day of week regardless of locale
            (DATEPART(dw, [DATE])  + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1
            -- Zero based week of month
            ,DATEPART(iso_week, [DATE]) % 53
                - DATEPART(iso_week, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH([DATE], -1))) % 53
            -- Zero based first day of month offset. Monday = 0 to Sunday =6
            ,(DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH([DATE], -1)))  + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7
        )
    ) X (WeekDayNumber, WeekOfMonth, FirstDayOfMonthOffset)
ORDER BY [DATE];
```